# Objective C or Swift Toolbar/Dockbar Example for Mac App

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift

I have been looking, without success on how to code a dock bar similar to the OSX Dock, that would be used in my application for navigation.

I would like to have an option bar at the bottom of the screen which would switch views, however I can't seem to find anything at all like that.

Any thoughts or pointers on where to start?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you mean like a UITabView?but for mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little bit unclear. Look at Jiaaro´s comment that can be a solution. On Apple´s Developer-Portal you can find the sample code UI-Catalogue. This project is both created in objective c and swift.

Comment: I wanted an animated dock bar similar to what you see on the desktop for OSX.  Not really a flat tab bar.  I'll take a look at that sample noted above.   Thanks.